# Alert sender has changed to no-reply@sharepointonline.com

Tags: list, office-365, email, alert

I have some alerts on several lists in our site collection (office 365), untill today the sender (from) of the alerts was the title of the site that the list belongs to. I don't know what we have done that the sender (from) has been changed to `no-reply@sharepointonline.com`. I would like to change it back to the site title.

How can I do it?

thanks and appreciate all kind of advice.

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior. I'm opening a service request with Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

It's not possible to change the outgoing e-mail address today, but it's a requested feature which may be implemented in the future.

I guess you where just lucky receiving another outgoing e-mail adress, since the default is [no-reply@sharepointonline.com](http://mailto:no-reply@sharepointonline.com).